# How do you detect changes in the DOM with jQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an nodejs express-based + mongodb website that I'd love to use with this library. What I would like to know is how would I detect changes in the order of elements in order to save their state. Submission of a form? jQuery functions?

Example:
I have a list of paragraphs that should appear on my `about.html` page. In my CMS I want to change their order. I go to the page that would let me sort the paragraphs, change their order, et cetera, and then click the save button. What needs to happen when I save?

I would love to hear any strategies or see any specific examples.

Comment: 1: It's not that difficult if you take a look at jqueryUI api docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) and specific examples of how to use sortables [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). 2: What needs to happend where ? in your jQuery, node.js, express or mongodb ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's starting point for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XsUCv/

The JS is:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#sortable").disableSelection();

$('input').on('click', function () {
    var sortedIDs = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize");
    alert(sortedIDs);
});
```

You'd then need to store the serialized order. When the page is next loaded the order should be fetched from the db and the `<li>`s printed in the order they were saved in.